# Bubble sort in Python, what are these arguments for?

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

```
def bbsort(list1):
    for passnum in range(len(list1)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range (passnum):
            if list1[i]>list1[i+1]:
                temp =list1[i]
                list1[i] = list1[i+1]
                list1[i+1] = temp
```

This is code for a bubble sort, but what is the use of `-1,0,-1` in the `while` condition?

Comment: That's not a `while` condition, that is a `for` loop.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking at arguments to the [*`range()` function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range); the numbers set up the range to start at the list length, minus one, then stepping down to 1 (the end point is not included in the range).

So there are 3 arguments, the first is `len(list1) - 1`, the second is `0` and the third is `-1`.

Say the list is length 5, then `range(5 - 1, 0, -1)` will produce a list with 4, 3, 2, and 1:

```
>>> list(range(4, 0, -1))
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The `for` loop steps over these values:

```
>>> for i in range(4, 0, -1):
...     print(i)
... 
4
3
2
1
```

The `for` loop assigns these numbers to `passnum`, and the next nested loop uses that to create a new `range()`. The first time, that inner range will go from `0` to `len(list1) - 1` (exclusive), the next time from `0` to `len(list1) - 2`, etc, until the last time, when it'll run from `0` to `1`, always excluding the stop index. For a list of length 5, that means the inner loop first assigns 0, 1, 2, 3 to `i`, then 0, 1, 2, then 0, 1, then 0.

The code is missing an opportunity to use Python sequence assignment to swap to elements:

```
def bbsort(list1):
    for passnum in range(len(list1) - 1, 0, -1):
        for i in range (passnum):
            if list1[i] > list1[i + 1]:
                list1[i], list1[i + 1] = list1[i + 1], list[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first -1 subtracts 1 from the length of the input list because the indexes start from 0, not 1. The 0 is the start number(only neccesary to get to the next parameter). The 2nd -1 is the step so that tells it to move backwards through the range.

Example:
range(5, 2, -1) is [5, 4, 3]

equal to range(start, stop, step)